# Post Form data with also some input files to Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest, asp.net-web-api

Is there any updated example to upload files with a form with fields and file inputs that post to a mvc4 webapi controller?

I am trying to post with Jquery axax to a asp.net mvc4 ApiController.
I used the [Jquery file Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for the client side part.
As the webapi seems not to support multiform data I tried to solve with [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1777847.aspx/1?MVC4%20Beta%20Web%20API%20and%20multipart%20form%20data) configuration formatter but still looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

(Scroll down to "Supporting Multipart MIME Data")

I have not actually tried this with the jQuery plugin, only with plain HTML forms.

Comment: Broken link.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-2 looks like it may have the answer though